# Is this possible with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel

Is this possible with PHPExcel to print an Array and have the different locations in the spreadsheet.

1. variable that contains the informations about the first row in landscape view 
   $array[A][1], $array[b][2]
2. variable that contains the secound
   $array[A][2], $array[B][2]

EDIT:

Right now I use this code.
The code just outputs the hole spreadsheet.

But I want more control of my echo's

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("kla.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

echo '<table border="1">' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
echo '<tr>' . "\n";
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
}
echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
```

**In the foreach I need every activity in every variable**
B2, B3, B4

next loop
C2, C3, C4

http://oi43.tinypic.com/2ajxhjo.jpg

Comment: I can't understand what this question actually means? What's the relevance of `landscape`?

Answer (score 0):

use `fromArray`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sheet, null, 'A1');
```

sheet is a 2 dimensional array. first dimension being the rows and the second dimension being the columns. `null` is provides the default value to a cell if the array has a null value. 3rd argument provide the starting point of the array data.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an array of cells from a worksheet by using the toArray() method:

```
/**
 * Create array from worksheet
 *
 * @param   mixed     $nullValue          Value returned in the array entry if a
 *                                            cell doesn't exist
 * @param   boolean   $calculateFormulas  Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param   boolean   $formatData         Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param   boolean   $returnCellRef      False - Return a simple array of rows and
 *                                            columns indexed by number counting from
 *                                            zero
 *                                        True - Return rows and columns indexed by
 *                                            their actual row and column IDs
 * @return  array
 */
```

So if you want the array indexed by row and column, ensure that the fourth argument is set to true

**EDIT**

Trying to guess what you mean by `loop`:

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= 2; $row++) {
    $rowDataArray = $objPHPExcel
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->rangeToArray(
            'A'.$row.':'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn().$row,
            null,
            true,
            true,
            true
        );
    var_dump($rowDataArray);
}
```

Comment: we have both sides covered :)

Comment: @DevZer0 - You couldn't understand the question either? Hopefully then, between us, we've answered it

Comment: I need to print only one column every loop. A1, B1, B2

The spreadsheet is like a scheme where every date is one the top (1, 2, 3, 4)
and the Activitys is on the left side (A, B, C, D)

Comment: OK, show your code and try explaining exactly what you want to do, because this is the first time you've mentioned the word loop... if you can't explain what you're trying to achieve, we can only guess what you mean